# implementing forloop on click addListener

Tags: javascript

I’m implementing google map to ionic, but I am facing a problem trying to implement marker and infowindow.

As you can see below, once I try to implement infowindow to each of marker, it works as intended:

```
this.markerStart[0].addListener('click',()=>{
             console.log('clicked')
             this.popuparray[0].open(this.map,this.markerStart[0]);
         })
         this.markerStart[1].addListener('click',()=>{
             console.log('clicked2222')
             this.popuparray[1].open(this.map,this.markerStart[1]);
         })
```

but when I try to modify it to use a for loop then it does not work.

It looks exactly same, but I don’t know why it doesn't work.

//here, this.markerStart.length is 2...but it doesn't work below in for loop.

```
console.log(this.markerStart);
    console.log(this.markerStart.length);
    console.log("this.markerStart")
    for(var j=0; j<this.markerStart.length; j++){
        this.markerStart[j].addListener('click',()=>{
            console.log(j);
            //only log 2 ...which is I don't understand. why log 2?
           // j should be 0 and 1...because this.markerStart.length is 2
            this.popuparray[j].open(this.map,this.markerStart[j])

        })
    }
```

I tried this as well:

```
  for(var j=0; j<2; j++){

        this.markerStart[j].addListener('click',()=>{
            console.log(j);
        })
    }
```

I thought at first that when I click the first marker it should log 1 and when clicking the second marker it should be log 2, but its only logging 2.

Comment: by the time click is called, `j` is `this.markerStart.length` - which is 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the last solution [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) works., so why you don't get the expected result. You can use `let` instead of `var` and it will work. `var` will keep your variable and for each iteration you will only change the only variable `j`. So after all you refer to a variable `j` which value is `2`. With `let` for each iteration a new variable will be created and each function will have it's own variable `j`.

```
 for(let j = 0; j < 2; j++){
     this.markerStart[j].addListener('click',() => console.log(j));
 }
```

Or if you want in the environment under `ES6`, you can use IIFE to create a scoped variable for the listeners

```
for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    ((k) => this.markerStart[k].addListener('click', () => console.log(k)))(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `var j=0;` with `let j=0;` in for loop and it will work as you expected.

Because `let` declares variable that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. On the other hand, `var` defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.